# How to handle navigation erros with "xamarin + Xam.Plugin.Webview" cross-platform

Tags: xamarin, webview, navigation, cross-platform

I am using xamarin + Xam.Plugin.Webview to build a cross-platform application "https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview"


Everything is fine, but I want to handle the navigation errors:
             1- why I get errors for linked css and js file in the web page?
             
2- How to read only errors which come from the page itself like, 404 and others.
             
3- I want to hide the webview from the form and show friendly page if I cannot load the content of the page.
             
4- Is there a way to keep navigation events rais only for the source link, not for the linked css or js files?


Finally, I tried to tack all the errors, e.g. "FormswebView_OnNavigationError". but sometimes I get 404 error, while the page is correctly working fine because this 404 error was just for a linked file "css, js, images" in the pages only which not prevent the page from working. I want to handle, "no connection", "cannot load", "server busy", and all kind of errors that will prevent the user to see the content. All solutions should be work in cross-platform, please.


In brief, how to know if the page finally displayed or not?

Update

Sorry, I am not a native english speaker.

I want just to know if my webpage is loaded or not.

I do not want the use to see any error pages.

I cannot count on "OnNavigationError" Event it is not usefull. It raised for some css, js errors, even if page is correctly loaded.

some times it raised 404 "not found" error for linked css, js files, and the webpage is loaded

I want to override all webview error pages.

I hope if I make it more clear

Regards


Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Sorry, it is too long to add a comment

As you see, these are all the Webview events:

    private void FormswebView_OnNavigationStarted(object sender, Xam.Plugin.WebView.Abstractions.Delegates.DecisionHandlerDelegate e)
        {

```
    }

    private void FormswebView_OnNavigationError(object sender, int e)
    {   
    //Sometimes I get e = 404, but this is just for a linked icon or css file
    //while the page is already existed and displayed
    //sometimes I get e = 404 for the page itself and "error page" displays instead of my page
    //How to know when to catch errors and override it?
    //How to overrid all the built-in error pages?
    }

    private void FormswebView_OnNavigationCompleted(object sender, string e)
    {

    }

    private void FormswebView_OnContentLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Now how to know if the page is loaded or not?
    }
```

Comment: Your description is vague. Can you provide a full error log?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native english speaker.
I want just to know if my webpage is loaded or not.
I do not want the use to see any error pages.
I cannot count on "OnNavigationError" Event it is not usefull. It raised for some css, js errors, even if page is correctly loaded.
some times it raised 404 "not found" error for linked css, js files, and the webpage is loaded
I want to override all webview error pages.
I hope if I make it more clear
Regards

Comment: Could you please provide an basic demo that can reproduce the issue, so that I can test it by my side

Comment: Thanks Lucas Zhang, I edit the post. Can you check, please?